# Get QtableWidget values to list in another QDialog

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I am making a plugin for QGIS 3.16 using PyQt5. I currently have three Qdialogs created with Qt Designer. One main dialog, and two popups.
The first popup contains a couple of lineEdits and doubleSpinBoxes, which when filled pass data into a QTableWidget in the main dialog. This works fine, but data is added *after* the main dialog is called, which I believe is causing part of the problem.

The second popup contains some dynamically added comboBoxes. I want to fill these comboBoxes with a list of items from the rows of the previously mentioned QTableWidget. However, when I try to create the list to fill the comboBox, it remains empty. How can I refer to the main dialog *after* the QTableWidget is filled, so that the list is properly filled?

Relevant snippet from the main dialog class (note that the base for the code was created by the QGIS plugin builder 3)

```py
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dialog_base.ui'))
FORM_CLASS_TAXA, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dialog_popup_taxa.ui'))
FORM_CLASS_VEGCOM, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(
    os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dialog_popup_vegcom.ui'))
class MainDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(MainDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.addNew_Taxa.clicked.connect(self.addNewTaxon)
        self.addNew_VegCom.clicked.connect(self.addNewVegCom)

    def addNewTaxon(self):
        """ Adds a new pollen taxon to the list of taxa by opening a pop-up in which the taxon short name can be given"""
        self.taxonPopup = AddTaxonPopup()
        self.taxonPopup.show()
        result = self.taxonPopup.exec_()
        # runs when apply is clicked on the add new taxon popup
        if result:
            # Get filled in values
            taxonShortName = self.taxonPopup.lineEdit_taxonShortName.text()
            # Check if entry is valid and add to table
            if taxonShortName:
                rowCount = self.tableWidget_Taxa.rowCount()
                self.tableWidget_Taxa.setRowCount(rowCount+1)
                self.tableWidget_Taxa.setItem(rowCount, 0, QTableWidgetItem(taxonShortName))
            else: 
                pass

    def addNewVegCom(self):
        """ Adds a new vegetation community to the list of communities by opening a pop-up in which a list of species
         and their percentages, as well as a new community name can be given"""
        self.vegComPopup = AddVegComPopup()
        self.vegComPopup.show()

        #add entries to table (not yet implemented)
        result = self.vegComPopup.exec_()
        if result:
            pass
```

code for popup 1 (since nothing has to be created dynamically, this simply refers to the .ui file, containing one lineEdit)

```py
class AddTaxonPopup (QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS_TAXA):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Popup Constructor."""
        super(AddTaxonPopup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

code for popup 2 (a little bit of a mess because it is partially created in the .ui file and partially here in the code)

```py
class AddVegComPopup (QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS_VEGCOM):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Popup Constructor."""
        super(AddVegComPopup, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        #events
        self.pushButton_vegComAddSpecies.clicked.connect(self.addVegComTaxonRow)

        #class variable for keeping count of the number of taxa
        self.previous = 0

        #add gridlayout to scrollarea
        self.frameforscrolling = QFrame(self.scrollArea)
        self.frameforscrolling.setLayout(self.gridLayout)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.frameforscrolling)

        #set locations of original .ui widgets in grid (because I couldn't get the grid to behave in Qt designer)

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_Title, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_Name, 1, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_2, 2, 1, 1, 3)

    def addVegComTaxonRow(self):
        """ Adds a new comboBox and doubleSpinBox to be able to add a new taxon to a vegetation community"""
        #get location of start OR previous taxon comboBox

        label = QLabel('Taxon ' + str(int((self.previous * 0.5)+1)), self)
        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        doubleSpin = QDoubleSpinBox()
        # insert the new widgets
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(label, self.previous+2, 0, 1, 4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, self.previous+3, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(doubleSpin, self.previous+3, 3, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_2, self.previous + 4, 0, 1, 4)
        self.previous += 2
        # Fill the comboBox HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
        self.taxonlist = []
        self.mainDialog = MainDialog()
        for taxon in range(self.mainDialog.tableWidget_Taxa.rowCount()):
            self.taxonlist.append(self.mainDialog.tableWidget_Taxa.item(taxon, 0).text())
        print(self.taxonlist)
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.taxonlist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in `AddVegComPopup.addVegComTaxonRow` you are creating a new instance of `MainDialog` and are extracting the item list from this new (hidden) widget rather than from the existing dialog that is shown on the screen. One way around this is to provide the list of items to the `AddVegComPopup` dialog at the moment you are initializing it in `MainDialog.addNewVegCom` and assign this list to an instance variable in `AddVegComPopup` so that you can access it every time you create a new drop box. For this, `MainDialog.addNewVegCom` would need to be changed to something like this:

```
def addNewVegCom(self):
    """ Adds a new vegetation community to the list of communities by opening a pop-up in which a list of species
    and their percentages, as well as a new community name can be given"""

    table = self.tableWidget_Taxa
    item_lst = [table.item(row, 0).text() for row in range(table.rowCount())]
    self.vegComPopup = AddVegComPopup(item_lst)
    result = self.vegComPopup.exec_()
    if result:
        pass
```

And `AddVegComPopup` would need to be updated according to

```
class AddVegComPopup (QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, taxonlist,  parent=None):   # note extra input parameter
        """Popup Constructor."""

        ... as before ...

        self.taxonlist = taxonlist

    ....

    def addVegComTaxonRow(self):
        """ Adds a new comboBox and doubleSpinBox to be able to add a new taxon to a vegetation community"""
        # this is the same as before
        label = QLabel('Taxon ' + str(int((self.previous * 0.5)+1)), self)
        self.comboBox = QComboBox()
        doubleSpin = QDoubleSpinBox()
        # insert the new widgets
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(label, self.previous+2, 0, 1, 4)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox, self.previous+3, 0, 1, 3)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(doubleSpin, self.previous+3, 3, 1, 2)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.buttonBox_2, self.previous + 4, 0, 1, 4)
        self.previous += 2
        
        # use predefined list
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.taxonlist)
```